# Assign an AMPScript (ExactTarget scripting language) variable the value of a field on my DOM?

Tags: javascript, exacttarget, ampscript

I work for ExactTarget and am using their proprietary scripting language "AMPScript".

Here's my code:

```
<script>
        function refreshGraph()
        {
            dateArray = new Array();
            countArray = new Array();

            %%[

            /* get all subscriber history for score of 1 */
            /* get the below score from the drop down list */
            SET @score = 1
            SET @subscriberScoringHistoryScoreRows = LOOKUPORDEREDROWS("subscriber_scoring_history", 5, "Date DESC", "score", @score, "Optin", "Yes")
...
```

Notice where I set the `@score` variable to 1.  I want to be able to set this variable via JavaScript.  Here's my drop down list whose value I want to use to set `@score` equal to:

```
Choose Score
    <select name="score" onchange="refreshGraph()">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
```

Does anyone have any ideas how to do this?

Comment: I could say the same thing.

Comment: _"I could say the same thing."_ Actually you can't. I. Didn't. Downvote. Your. Other. Question. Do I need to make that clearer for you?

Comment: @j08691 - Let me explain a little more clear.  When I said "I could say the same thing", I meant: "First of all dude, I didn't downvote your question. Don't make assumptions."

Comment: @j08691 - Are we good, or should we keep this non-constructive, argumentative conversation going, only to be deleted by a moderator?

Comment: BTW - you should post this on salesforce.stackexchange.com and tag it exacttarget.

Answer (score 0):

ET's AMPSCript and SSJS run on the server-side only and are only evaluated at page load.